# OpenGL ES, add texture to circle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm drawing a circle in OpenGL ES and when adding a texture it is "added" 4 times instead of 1 (see the image below).

[image]

In other words, that is my picture x4. What I want is the nuke symbol centered as one picture in the circle.

Below is my method (in the Circle class) for drawing the circle using a texture

```
public void drawTexture(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display) 

    // Enable vertex-array and define its buffer
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Enable texture-coords-array
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords


    // Draw the primitives from the vertex-array directly

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numberOfVertices);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

}
```

At the moment, the texBuffer is the same as the vertexBuffer (maybe the problem?) since it has to have the same amount of points and I don't know which points if not the vertices.

Below is my method for loading the texture as well as the method where I set up my vertices for the texture.

```
public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]); // Bind to texture ID
    // Set up texture filters
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Construct an input stream to texture image
    InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.nuke);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        // Read and decode input as bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
    } finally {
        try {
            istream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}

private void setUpTextureVertices(float radius) {
    float theta = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices-1));
    float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
    float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);
    float x = radius;
    float y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        texVertices[i][0] = x;
        texVertices[i][1] = y;
        float t = x;
        x = (c * x - s * y + 1) * 0.5f;
        y = (s * t + c * y + 1) * 0.5f;
    }
}

private void setUpVertices(float radius) {
    float theta = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices-1));
    float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
    float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);
    float x = radius;
    float y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        vertices[i][0] = x;
        vertices[i][1] = y;
        float t = x;
        x = c * x - s * y;
        y = s * t + c * y;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added the constructor for the Circle class

```
public Circle() {

    setUpVertices(1.0f);
    // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. A float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4 * 2);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert byte buffer to float

    // Loop through the vertices and put them in the vertexbuffer
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices[i][j]); // Copy data into buffer
        }
    }
    vertexBuffer.position(0); // Rewind

    setUpTextureVertices(1.0f);

    // Setup texture-coords-array buffer, in float. An float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4 * 2);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
    // Loop through the vertices and put them in the vertexbuffer
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            texBuffer.put(texVertices[i][j]); // Copy data into buffer
        }
    }
    texBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your uv goes from -1 to 1 . Make sure they go from 0 to 1 .

The lowest value for a sinus is -1 , while the highest goes to 1.

formula would be

```
 x = (c * x - s * y +1) *0.5f;
 y = ( s * t + c * y +1)*0.5f;
```

Comment: Is this only for the vertices of the texture or the whole circle? Should I make a method to set the texture vertices with this being the only difference?

Comment: This is only for the "vertices" of the texture :). The coordinates in Texture space are called UV (so the buffer you pass in glTexCoordPointer function call). A vertex (plural vertices) is composed of both positions (XYZ) and UV.

Comment: Okey, because the result was rather gnarly, though it looks like only one picture was rendered it was impossible to see what the picture reassembled. I will complement the code in my question.

Comment: This might have to do with the fact that you are using a triangle fan approach (and you can see the center of the circle beeing in the right-side , where vertex1 is positioned). Try making the 1st vertex in the center (so 0,0 as positions, 0.5, 0.5 as uvs) then, generate the other vertices according to your algorithm. Also, for textures, the "radius" will always be 1.0f (keep that in mind when you want to draw a bigger circle).

Comment: Btw, I think i found something else. For uvs x should be x = (sin(theta) +1) / 2 , while y = (cos(theta)+1)/2 . Your formula seems to rotate the point in 2D , and you don't want that . So texVertices[0][0] = 0.5 , texVertices[0][1] = 0.5 , then texVertices[1..n][0] = (sin(theta+1))/2 , texVertices[1..n][1]=(cos(theta+1))/2 . This should give you the uvs according to a triangle fan with the 1st vertex in the center. Make sure your vertex position formula follows the same rules as well or you might get another fuzzy looking texture.Start by drawing a 5 vertices circle for more clarity(a square)!

Comment: private void setUpTextureVertices(float radius) {
  float theta = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices-1));
  float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
  float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);
  x = 0.5f;
  y = 0.5f;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
   texVertices[i][0] = x;
   texVertices[i][1] = y;
   x = (s+1)/2;
   y = (c+1)/2;
  }
 }
I've written it like that (if I've understood you correctly), and this is the result http://i.imgur.com/1dFdE9U.png :/ I'm sorry that I'm so bad at this but this circle has made me furious...

Comment: Since you mentioned the triangle_fan, is that a bad approach and is there a better way?

Comment: People don't usually use triangle_fan . It's not a bad approach, but it can be missleading at times. The most use method is from OGL2.0 and is drawprimitives with indexses. You can use triangle fan method, just make sure to know how the triangles are drawn (in what order, and what vertices they take).

Comment: Please try first to reduce the number of vertices to 5 so things will become more obvious.