# Android OpenGL Circle Texture Doubled

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, geometry

I am trying to draw Circle with texture on it which should be stretched on all vertices.

The problem is that the result i get looks like this:

http://s14.postimg.org/3wyb74469/image.png

I have tried to draw triangle fan as it need to be , first coordinates at 0,0,0
And rest as needed:

http://escience.anu.edu.au/lecture/cg/surfaceModeling/image/surfaceModeling015.png

Also here is the same question and I couldn't get answer for my problem from it :

[OpenGL ES, add texture to circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837719/opengl-es-add-texture-to-circle)

Loading circle vertices coordinates function:

```
private final int mVerticesDataSize = 3;    
private final int mNumberOfVertices = 180;
private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;   
private float[] vertices;
private  FloatBuffer mVerticesBuff;

public void loadCircleVerticesBuff(Context mActivityContext){

       mVerticesBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mNumberOfVertices * mVerticesDataSize * mBytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();                            
       vertices = new float[mNumberOfVertices * mVerticesDataSize];
       float theta = 0;


       for (int i = 0; i < (mNumberOfVertices * mVerticesDataSize); i += 3) {   
       vertices[i] = (float) (((float) 5*Math.cos(theta)));
       vertices[i + 1] = (float) ((float) 5*Math.sin(theta));
       vertices[i + 2] = 0;
       theta += Math.PI / 90;
       }

       mVerticesBuff.put(vertices);
       mVerticesBuff.position(0);          
}
```

Loading circle texture coordinates function:

```
private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 3;
public void loadCircleTextureBuff(){
    mCircleTextureCoordinatesBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mNumberOfVertices * mTextureCoordinateDataSize * mBytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();                          
    mCircleTextureCoordinatesBuff.put(vertices);
    mCircleTextureCoordinatesBuff.position(0);
}
```

The opengl function used to draw is  :

```
 GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, mNumberOfVertices);
```

Comment: I've never used OpenGL directly, but in my experience with SFML it looks like your texture isn't being "stretched". Your sprite is smaller than the surface you're painting to, and so it's painted in a repeating pattern (default behavior). Is there a way to set your texture/sprite to zoom/stretch?

Comment: Hi ^^ Normally yeah this is the solution...but unfortenetly not in this case, this is not the texture image size ): but maybe yeah i forgot to use some stretch flag but idk which one it is . please look at the third link i gave its same problem " OpenGL ES, add texture to circle"

Comment: The question you link has an answer. While it's short, I think it explains the solution clearly. You can't use the same values for the vertex positions and texture coordinates to get the desired result. Either define a separate vertex attribute with the correct texture coordinates, or shift/scale the values in your vertex shader.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So solution found (: 1 very very importent thing i missed up / or openGL missed up.

Texture coordinates can be only in range of 0 to 1 .

So here is the trick/solution :

```
//Build vertices :
vertices[i] = (float) (((float) raduis*Math.cos(theta)))+raduis;
vertices[i + 1] = (float) ((float) raduis*Math.sin(theta))+raduis;

// Build texture :
 for (int i = 0; i < (mNumberOfVertices * mVerticesDataSize); i += 3) {   
           vertices[i] = (vertices[i])/(raduis*2);
           vertices[i + 1] = (vertices[i+1])/(raduis*2);
           vertices[i + 2] = 0;
  }
```

And here is the res :

http://s2.postimg.org/tno4jr4y1/image.png

Dont forget to flip texture vertices as i forgot (: